# Google Search Console API request with PHP

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-search-console

I want to request query data from the Google Search Console API via a PHP script, but I don't get it running. I had a look into the examples, but there are not too much, especially for PHP. I created a project in the Google Cloud Platform, added everything as described. I have no problem to get Google Analytics Data via a PHP script, but Search Console is not working.
Here is the code how I tried it:

```
// Load the Google API PHP Client Library.
require_once __DIR__ . '/google-client-library/vendor/autoload.php';

use Google\Client;
use Google\Service\SearchConsole;
use Google\Service\SearchConsole\SearchAnalyticsQueryRequest;

$site = "https://www.example.com";

$KEY_FILE_LOCATION = __DIR__ . '/google-api-keys/client_secret_xxxxx.json';
putenv("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=$KEY_FILE_LOCATION");
$client = new Google\Client();
// I don't think this is really necessary as the environment variable is already set.
$client->setAuthConfig($KEY_FILE_LOCATION);
$client->setApplicationName("Search Console Request");
$client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters.readonly");
$searchConsole = new SearchConsole([$client, $site]);

$queryRequest = new SearchAnalyticsQueryRequest();
$queryRequest->setStartDate("2022-04-01");
$queryRequest->setEndDate("2022-04-04");
$queryRequest->setDimensions(["QUERY","PAGE"]);

$response = $searchConsole->searchanalytics->query($site, $queryRequest);

echo $response;
```

And this is the PHP Log message:

```
[09-Apr-2022 07:48:40 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Google\Service\Exception: {
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Login Required.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "required",
        "location": "Authorization",
        "locationType": "header"
      }
    ],
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
        "reason": "CREDENTIALS_MISSING",
        "domain": "googleapis.com",
        "metadata": {
          "service": "searchconsole.googleapis.com",
          "method": "google.searchconsole.v1.searchanalytics.SearchAnalyticsService.Query"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

What I am doing wrong? How do I get the right credentials without User interaction. This should be a script which runs periodically and get the data for later use.

Comment: Hi Michael, was your issue resolved and how? Please guide as I am facing same issue. I want to fetch data from GSC via API

Answer (score 0):

you need to update the following line

```
$KEY_FILE_LOCATION = __DIR__ . '/google-api-keys/client_secret_xxxxx.json';
```

with a correct path of your google cloud credentials at your machine, you can get this credentials data from you google cloud account at the credentials section , please refer to [google cloud Api documentation to get more details](https://cloud.google.com/api-keys/docs/get-started-api-keys)

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response, but this was only for the example. In my script I have a correct path to my credentials.json.
I generated it how it was described in your posted link, and it worked till point 4. But when I use it in my script I still get the same error message as shown in my original post.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
$searchConsole = new SearchConsole([$client, $site]);
```

to

```
$searchConsole = new SearchConsole($client);
```

If you give an array there, the library will try to instantiate a "Client" class with that config which is probably not what you want

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).